# Which Methods Open A File in Python

Tags: python, file

Im trying to run code which writes its outputs to a bunch of files (upwards of 250). Im currently using:

```
with open(self.file, self.mode, newline='') as file_writer:
            writer = csv.writer(file_writer)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

This should auto close my files but I'm still getting the following:

```
    52 of 231 | Analysing player: Evolved ANN 5 Noise 05 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fullAnalysis.py", line 200, in <module>
    run_one.start()
  File "fullAnalysis.py", line 179, in start
    print_output=False)
  File "/home/vi/td/axelrod-dojo/src/axelrod_dojo/algorithms/genetic_algorithm.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.pool = Pool(processes=self.processes)
  File "/home/vi/.conda/envs/project/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 119, in Pool
    context=self.get_context())
  File "/home/vi/.conda/envs/project/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 174, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/home/vi/.conda/envs/project/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 239, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "/home/vi/.conda/envs/project/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/home/vi/.conda/envs/project/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 277, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/home/vi/.conda/envs/project/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 26, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/home/vi/.conda/envs/project/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 72, in _launch
    parent_r, child_w = os.pipe()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

My question is, which methods open files in python so I can find this leak and plug it?

I currently the only file methods I'm useing is a mixture of:

- `os.makedirs()`
- `os.remove()`
- `csv.writerow()` (as show with closure)

(This is the second time its happened on #52 after implementing the with closure code)

### EDIT

Below is the main section of code at the top of the trace for fullAnalysis.py:

```
        for opponent in self.opponent_list:
        print(i, "of", len(self.opponent_list), "| Analysing player:", str(opponent), "...")

        global_processes = 20

        # Stochastic players need seeding
        if opponent.classifier['stochastic']:
            opponent = self._get_seeded_player_class(type(opponent))(self.global_seed)
            global_processes = 1

        population = axl_dojo.Population(params_class=axl_dojo.CyclerParams,
                                         params_kwargs=cycler_kwargs,
                                         size=POPULATION_SIZE,
                                         # processes=global_processes,
                                         population=getPreMadePop(POPULATION_SIZE),
                                         objective=cycler_objective,
                                         output_filename=self._get_file_name(opponent),
                                         opponents=[opponent],
                                         print_output=False)

        population.run(GENERATION_LENGTH)
        print("{:.2f}% Done.\tSaved to:".format((100 * i) / len(self.opponent_list)),
              self._get_file_name(opponent))
        TRACKER.print_diff()
        # self.output_files[str(opponent)] = self._get_file_name(opponent)
        i += 1
```

Below is the init code for the axelrod_dojo genetic_algorthm.py:

```
 def __init__(self, params_class, params_kwargs, size, objective, output_filename,
             bottleneck=None, mutation_probability=.1, opponents=None,
             processes=1, weights=None,
             sample_count=None, population=None, print_output=True):
    self.params_class = params_class
    self.bottleneck = bottleneck
    self.print_output = print_output
    if processes == 0:
        self.processes = cpu_count()
    else:
        self.processes = processes

    self.pool = Pool(processes=self.processes)
```

Comment: `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files` seems contradictory to your assumption of your code automatically closing files

Comment: Could you share the entire code? It's worth noting that your program did not fail on one of the lines you've shown us.

Comment: Ive added the code that run before crashing. Is there a chance it could be something to do with closing/opening files on different threads using the multiprocessing tool?